# Do the ship missile expansions actually do anything?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

In Metroid Prime 3, you can collect a handful of `Ship Missile Expansions`, which supposedly add one to the number of missiles your ship can carry.  Does this actually do anything?  You really only use your ship to bomb targets a few times throughout the game, and I never had problems with the ship lacking firepower, so this power up seems kind of silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I no longer have the game, but I remember finding out long after I'd beaten the game that you could actually use ship missiles to bomb enemies when meeting certain specifications... I think it was the area had to be outdoors, and you had to scan the enemies to engage the ship or something along those lines.

This is purely from memory, though, so might not be accurate, but should be pretty close.

Comment: This is pretty accurate, although there are some outdoor areas where you can't use the ship missiles anyways, such as when you fight the Korakk Beast and its rider.